# Setting the selected cell on DataGridView causes a hidden exception

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I have a `DataGridView` that is filled using an `OleDbDataAdapter`. However, I realized when I try to set the current selected row (cell) on my `DataGridView`, a hidden exception occurs. I have removed the `try-catch` block so that the exception is thrown. It is most probably a `NullReferenceException`. But once the program passes this line, the rest of the lines on my method are ignored and my form shows some strange behavior. For example the close box on the form suddenly disappears.

This is the snipped of code when I load my records and try to fill my `DataGridView`:

```
dgvCampaigns.DataSource = dsCampaigns;
dgvCampaigns.DataMember = "Campaigns";
dgvCampaigns.Columns["Id"].Visible = false;
dgvCampaigns.Columns["RowNum"].Visible = false;

if (dsCampaigns.Tables["Campaigns"].Rows != null)
    if (dsCampaigns.Tables["Campaigns"].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        mngSelectedIndex = 0;
        dgvCampaigns.CurrentCell = dgvCampaigns[0, 0];
    }                  
if (dgvCampaigns.CurrentCell != null)
    pnlManageCampaignActivities.Enabled = true;
lblCurrentPage.Text = mngCurrentPage.ToString();
lblTotalPages.Text = mngPagesCount.ToString();
lblCampaignCount.Text = mngCampaignCount.ToString();
lblLastRefreshedValue.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
UpdatePaginationLinkValues();
```

The line that causes this problem is

```
dgvCampaigns.CurrentCell = dgvCampaigns[0, 0];
```

After this line, the rest of the lines are ignored and no `Exception` is thrown.

Comment: is this code in form_load?

Comment: @HPT form_load calls a method that contains this code. So it is not directly form_load but it triggers on it.

Comment: this is a know problem
check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4934010/3970411) and also you can read more [here](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/)